# XmlpullParserException while invoking the SOAP web services in android

Tags: android, web-services, soap

With the code below, I am getting this error:

> 08-20 12:01:01.606: WARN/System.err(939): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG @1:6 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4052df28)

Please give me idea where I go wrong.

This is the code I wrote:

```
          SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
               SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                 SoapEnvelope.VER12);
               envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
               try {
                       
                       HttpTransportSE  httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                       httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
              // httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
               SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                    Log.i("Result........................", result.toString());
                    System.out.println(result);
                    Toast.makeText(SAPSoapWebservicesActivity.this, result.toString(),
                                50000).show();
                                               
             } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (Exception e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

Comment: may be your Xml not formatted,check the start end tags

Comment: @Jenuine Can I give Input string to the request in xml format?

Comment: +1 since SOAP calls can get complex to debug

Comment: i read one artcle like this issue i will giv u the link here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/tYWGK26Tn9I%5B1-25%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG"
```

`XML Parsing Error`. When pre-required formatted **Response** is not received from the Server,while Parsing,the parser pushes this Exception.

Suggestions:

- Before `Parsing the response` from Server,just go on to trace it by toasting or printing it on the `LogCat`.
- Check the `Parameters` that you are passing to the `Web Service Method` that you are calling.If the required `parameter or the method name does not match`,it will give you an un appropiate response which while parsing will give this Exception as the Parser would be expecting `"something else"`.